# Can overcharging destroy Xperia J or Android phone?

Tags: sony-xperia-j

My phone needs to charge for about only 2 and half hour, but I forgot so I charged my phone for about 3 and half hour. Then I noticed that my battery is easy to drain. When my phone is in 14% or below, it will tell me that I already need to charge but when I turn off my phone and turn it on again, it will go back to 16%. Also when my phone is already 100% charged and I turn it off and on again, it will be at 95% left. Can overcharging destroy a Xperia J or Android phone?

Comment: Your question is very hard to follow so people are unlikely to answer if they can't understand what you're saying could you write it in sentences please.

Answer (score 3):

If an Android device is connected to a charger for a long period of time, with poor ventilation, this can contribute to overheating the device.

Apart from that, modern devices and batteries will stop charging when the battery is fully charged. There's a builtin failsafe that will cut off the power, as to prevent overcharging. Additionally there's is also a Short Circuit Protection.

As per your device in particular, you can read from the [User's Manual](http://www-support-downloads.sonymobile.com/st26/userguide_EN_ST26i_2_Android4.1.pdf) *(page 13)*:

> Charging the phone over a long period of time, for example, overnight, does not damage the battery or the phone.

Comment: I'd delete the first paragraph, because damage by overheating is not connected to leaving the charger plugged in. As soon as the phone is full, it only draws standby current and leaves the battery charged and goes to sleep as without charger plugged in. Car analogy: driving for 12 hours does also not harm its battery either, the charger circuit takes care of it.

Comment: @ce4 What do you think now?

Comment: All's fine, your answer is (and was already) good :-) I often get annoyed by rumours in this field, like battery charging was something mystical... http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33003/is-there-any-sense-in-this-technique-for-charging-li-ion-batteries

Comment: Aaand, this one: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36248/consequence-effects-and-solutions-mobile-phone-always-connected-to-ac-power